# Missing icons in a GNOME app in XFCE

Tags: xfce, contacts

I'm running Xubuntu (12.10). I was looking for a simple standalone contacts manager and ended up installing gnome-contacts. Some of the icons appear don't seem to be showing up properly though:

[image: missing gnome-contacts icons]

Is there a way of fixing this?

Comment: Have you tried *other* icons?

Comment: @UriHerrera Can you elaborate a bit? Wasn't really aware I could simply change icons on GNOME apps.

Comment: I mean the theme, another icon theme.

Comment: Tried switching between a few that came with my Xubuntu installation (GNOME, Humanity) but the only change was the magnifying glass icon in the search box.

Comment: Is your Gnome contacts version 3.6.0?, because if it is your Icons are (GNOME specifically) are missing the new icons 3.6.X apps need.

Comment: Have you tried themes `Tango` or `elementary`?